# Trying to call the correct method

Tags: java, class, methods

```
public class Xy {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    }
```

Main.

```
public class Gk extends Xy {

public Gk(String a, double b, int c){
    super(a, b, c);
}

public void printIR(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}
```

Second Class.

I have figured out how to call a method from the second class to the main class with:

```
Gk test1 = new Gk(a,b,c);
```

But when I try to call the method printIR to the main class with the same code i get a error, I think im missing something. Can someone help me out?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: missing `public Xy(String a, double b, int c);` in `Xy class`: it's the *constructor*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Gk(a,b,c);`is not a method. That is a constuctor of the class. If you what to call a method you must have an object in your calse test1 and on this you can call the method:

```
test1.printIR();
```

Comment: can't be so obvious!! :D

Comment: Thanks this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Can't believe It was!! :D

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is

```
public Gk(String a, double b, int c){
   super(a, b, c); // you need a matching constructor in Xy
}
```

Here from `Constructor` of `Gk` is calling it's `supper`. In this case `supper` is `Xy`. But you didn't implement such a `Constructor` there.

You can try something similar to this.

```
public class XY {
  public XY(String a, double b, int c){

  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new GK("a",2,3).printIR();
  }
 }

public class GK extends XY{
  public GK(String a, double b, int c){
    super(a, b, c);
  }
  public void printIR(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
}
```